# A set that is not an ordinal

Tags: logic, set-theory, ordinals

According to what I heard of, an ordinal is constructed by taking an union of {$\alpha$} $\cup$ $\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a predecessor ordinal.

If so, how can there be a set that is not an ordinal?

Comment: By the way, not all ordinals are constructed in this way. That only gives _successor_ ordinals; _limit ordinals_ do not have this form.

Comment: Also, don't confuse the notion of a set _being_ an ordinal with a set being a _subset_ of an ordinal, or a set being in one-to-one correspondence with an ordinal (which is, of course, equivalent to the Axiom of Choice, since it implies that every set can be well-ordered.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$\varnothing$ is an ordinal; we call it $0$.

$0\cup\{0\}=\varnothing\cup\{\varnothing\}=\{\varnothing\}=\{0\}$ is an ordinal; we call it $1$.

$1\cup\{1\}=\{\varnothing\}\cup\{\{\varnothing\}\}=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}=\{0,1\}$ is an ordinal; we call it $2$.

$2\cup\{2\}=\{0,1\}\cup\{2\}=\{0,1,2\}$ is an ordinal; we call it $3$.

$\{0,2\}$ is not an ordinal: it is not $x\cup\{x\}$ for any ordinal $x$.

Answer (score 9):

The power set of an ordinal is usually not an ordinal, except for the cases of $0$ and $1$.

For example, $\mathcal P(\omega)$ is *not* an ordinal.

Answer (score 9):

An even simpler example of a set that is not an ordinal would be $\{\{\emptyset \}\}$.  We have $\emptyset \in \{\emptyset\} \in \{\{\emptyset \}\}$ but $\emptyset \notin \{\{\emptyset \}\}$.